# What should our main site chatroom be called?

Tags: discussion, chat

Every Stack Exchange site has at least one chatroom associated to it. The primary chatroom for the site usually has an interesting name which is somehow evocative of the topic of that site: for instance, [the h Bar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) at [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com), [the Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) at [Puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com), [The Screening Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room) at [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com).

**What should we call [the main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72781/constructed-languages) for Constructed Languages SE?**

Answer (score 19):

## **[Babel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Babel)**

or the tower thereof.

Comment: Babel is about diversity in natural languages, it has no conlang appeal to me.

Comment: Btw. [The Conlang Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language#/media/File:Conlangflag.svg) represents the Tower of Babel against a rising sun.

Comment: I am okay with this idea. But I have one concern: [Babel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Babel) gives me a sense of confusion.

Comment: Perhaps a variation on this like "Rebuilding Babel" could indicate the conlang specificity...

Answer (score 8):

**Xenoglossia Speech Center**

Taken from the word **xenoglossy**.

> [Xenoglossy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenoglossy), also written xenoglossia, sometimes also known as xenolalia, is the putative paranormal phenomenon in which a person is able to speak or write a language he or she could not have acquired by natural means. The words derive from Greek ξένος (xenos), "foreigner" and γλῶσσα (glōssa), "tongue" or "language". The term xenoglossy was ostensibly coined by French parapsychologist Charles Richet in 1905. Stories of xenoglossy are found in the Bible, and contemporary claims of xenoglossy have been made by parapsychologists and reincarnation researchers such as Ian Stevenson. There is no scientific evidence that xenoglossy is an actual phenomenon.

Closely related to Xenoglossy is the word glossolia or the gift of tongues!

> [Glossolalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossolalia) or speaking in tongues is a phenomenon in which people appear to speak in languages unknown to them. One definition used by linguists is the fluid vocalizing of speech-like syllables that lack any readily comprehended meaning, in some cases as part of religious practice in which it is believed to be a divine language unknown to the speaker.
>
> Sometimes a distinction is made between "glossolalia" and "xenolalia" or "xenoglossy", which specifically designates when the language being spoken is a natural language previously unknown to the speaker.

Answer (score 4):

## The Xenolinguistic Ziggurat

Inspired by the answers from Pikalek and Ken Graham, this name combines the idea of alien languages with the Tower of Babel (a ziggurat).

Answer (score 2):

## ˈkɒnlaŋ

As per *conlang* [pronunciation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conlang).

Comment: One problem with this suggestion: different speakers pronounce the word in different ways. Is it /ˈkɒnlaŋ/? /ˈkɒnleɪŋ/? /ˈkɑnlæŋ/?

Answer (score 2):

## The Language Art.

*(with the dot (`.`) at the end)*

Considerations:

- *"Art."* is a common abbreviation for *"artificial"*;
- The unusual order of *"art"* and *"language"* is an appeal to the fact that many conlangs, indeed, do have unusual word order;
- Creating a language *is*, indeed, art.

Comment: I mean, I like puns but … hmmm …

Answer (score 0):

### The Language Factory

<sub>Inspired by [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/)'s "The Factory Floor".</sub>

Comment: Worldbuilding's 'The Factory Floor' is a reference to the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. It is a sub-dimension where the Magratheans construct new planets (worlds) to the specifications of their customers. I don't think the reference translates well to languages, especially when changing wording :/

Answer (score -1):

## Appendix F

Appendix F is the appendix in the single volume edition of Lord of the Rings that describes the languages of Middle Earth. It also is found at the back of the book and only the most dedicated read the appendices, much like the chat rooms.

Comment: It's a bit obscure ... and, also, related only to one family of constructed languages. I was hoping for a chatroom name which isn't specifically Tolkien or specifically Klingon or anything, to convey the idea that everyone is welcome.

Comment: I would say being obscure is a pro, not a con. :-) As for conveying that everyone is welcome, it's still generic enough. Physics has h-bar which is a fundamental constant in quantum dynamics, but no one would assume Newtonian mechanics discussions wouldn't be welcome there.

Answer (score -1):

## The [Syllabary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabary)

From Wikipedia:

> A syllabary is a set of written symbols that represent the syllables or (more frequently) moras which make up words.

Answer (score -2):

## The Dictionary

Because we do languages, get it? :D

Answer (score -3):

## **tʃæt ɹuːm**

Chat room written using the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:International_Phonetic_Alphabet).

Note: this may have errors - if you're better at IPA than me, feel free to edit it accordingly. Also, meɪn tʃæt ɹuːm might be more specific..

Comment: I like this, but it would be more interesting to maybe spell *conlang* or *artifical languages* or something along that line phonetically

Comment: Feel free to riff on my suggestion. Maybe ɑː(ɹ)təˈfɪʃəl  tʃæt ?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better name for [linguistics.se] chat?

Comment: Maybe. Looks like they already have one called lɪŋˈgwɪstɪks.

Answer (score -3):

**The Round Table** as known in all King Arthur's legends.

> **As its name suggests, it has no head, implying that everyone who sits there has equal status.** The table was first described in 1155 by Wace, who relied on previous depictions of Arthur's fabulous retinue. The symbolism of the Round Table developed over time; by the close of the 12th century it had come to represent the chivalric order associated with Arthur's court, the Knights of the Round Table. - [Round Table (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_Table).

This give the chat room a sense of nobility!

Comment: The room name should really connect the room to the site's topic in some way, though. . .

Answer (score -4):

**St Hildegard's**

I would frequent a pub with that name.

Comment: Bingo!... I mean, Bingen.

Answer (score -8):

**The International ConLang Center** would be cool to me.